# Automation to add a LF and CR (EOL) to the end of multiple .csv files

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, eol

I have a bunch of `.csv` files that are generated externally and sent to me periodically. they each contain a single row of text with 31 "columns". None of them, however, have any kind of `EOL` (no LF by itself or with CR), so when I attempt to combine any of these files, I get more columns on the same row, instead of a row for each file.

I would like a way to automatically add this to the end of each of these files in a batch, with the outputs having the same filename as the original file, potentially with the addition of a character at the beginning of the name so I new this process was completed. `Ex: originalFile.csv>> 1_originalFile.csv`.

I had attempted to create a file called "`eol.csv`" that was simply (LF and CR), and create a batch that would add that to the end of all of my files, but as I am a novice to writing batch files, I was significantly unsuccessful.

If it were possible for this to execute on each file as it were dropped into a folder, that would be even better.

Thanks for any thoughts on this!

Comment: You should be able to just `echo. >>originalFile.csv`

Comment: thanks! so what would a batch of that look like?

`For file in *csv; do
echo. >>"$file"
done.`

Comment: Also, providing any attempt of your own code is appreciated, as this site mainly helps with errors in code, but generally people will still help, and don't forget to "check" an answer that you think solves or helps the most.

Comment: @drumtechjp - that's bash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search all `.csv` file names for the string `_fixed`, and on any who fail to have it, will insert a blank line and rename it. Of course replace the `pathToWherever` with the correct path for you, and the `/s` option can be added to allow searching in subfolders in the named path too.

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\pathToWherever\" %%G in (*.csv) do (
    echo %%G | findstr /c:"_fixed" || (
        echo:>>%%G
        ren "%%G" "%%~nG_fixed.csv" 
    )
)
```

Comment: This worked well, thank you!
...once I realized that the folder I was using as a test had " - copy" at the end, which when inserted directly into the code obviously did not behave as expected, as it saw copy as a function.  After renaming the folder all worked as expected!

Comment: @drumtechjp - As written, this code appends an unwanted space to the line as well. Easily fixed by removing the space before the redirection. But see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35930672/1012053) for an even simpler solution that avoids renaming any files.

Comment: @dbenham ah, having a space before the redirection is a habit to avoid oddities about echo'ing everything or just errors etc, likely not needed here but one i may never break, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @drumtechjp Ah, or quotes couldve been added to the path option, but too late for that now.

Answer (score 4):

The FINDSTR regular expression `$` recognizes end of line as the position immediately before a carriage return. So `findstr /v $` will only match lines that do not contain a carriage return. You can use this fact to append carriage return/linefeed to only files that need it, without having to rename any files.

The following one liner from the command line is all you need:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('findstr /m /v $ *.csv') do @(echo()>>"%F"
```

Double up the percents if you put the command within a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

Since all `echo`s end in a CRLF, and you can use `echo/` to echo a CLRF by itself, you can simply use output redirection to append a CLRF to each of the csv files.

If you want to run this on a bunch of files that you've dragged and dropped onto the script, it would look like this:

```
@for %%A in (%*) do echo/ >>%%A
```

That one line is the entire script, by the way.

Comment: You should not use `echo.` to output empty lines, and certainly never suggest a beginner to use it. I use `echo/` for empty lines and `echo(%var%` when "var" may be empty or contain _any_ value, even "/?". Detais [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774) and on multiple posts about this topic here and there...

Comment: As written, this appends an unwanted space to the end of the line. Easily fixed by removing the space before the redirection. But you haven't done anything to prevent the file from being "fixed" multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to append a line-break to (the last line of) a file if not yet present:

1. [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

   ```cmd
   findstr /V "$" "data.csv" > nul && echo/>> "data.csv"
   ```

   This inverse (`/V`) search matches the last line only when it is not terminated by a line-break. In such case [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) lets the following command execute, which just appends a line-break.

   Restrictions:

   - lines must be shorter than 8K characters;
2. [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html):

   ```cmd
   < "data.csv" find /V "" > "data.csv.tmp" && move /Y "data.csv.tmp" "data.csv" > nul
   ```

   This search matches all lines, `find` appends a line-break to every returned line, even for the last one when there is none. A temporary file is required since it is not possible to read from and write to the same file. If no errors occur, [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) lets the next command execute, which moves the temporary file onto the original one.

   Restrictions:

   - this requires a temporary file;
   - lines must be shorter than 4K characters;
3. [`more`](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html):

   ```cmd
   more "data.csv" > "data.csv.tmp" && move /Y "data.csv.tmp" "data.csv" > nul
   ```

   This just returns all lines; `more` appends a line-break to every returned line, even for the last one when there is none. A temporary file is required since it is not possible to read from and write to the same file. If no errors occur, [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) lets the next command execute, which moves the temporary file onto the original one.

   Restrictions:

   - this requires a temporary file;
   - the file must be shorter than 64K lines;
   - lines must be shorter than 64K characters;
   - <kbd>TABs</kbd> become expanded to <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>;
4. [`sort`](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html):

   ```cmd
   sort "data.csv" /+65535 /REC 65535 | sort /+65535 /REC 65535 /O "data.csv"
   ```

   This just returns all lines; `sort` appends a line-break to every returned line, even for the last one when there is none. Surprisingly, no temporary file is required (I tested with a ~ 30 MB file without data loss due to I/O collisions). Nevertheless, this is likely the slowest method here because of the pipe ([`|`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)).

   The key is to set a character position for sorting that is beyond the data. In such cases, `sort` seems to simply revert the whole file; this is the reason for using two `sort` commands. But I tested it just very quickly with one file on Windows 7, so you should be cautious with this.

   Restrictions:

   - lines must be shorter than 64K characters;

All of the above approaches can easily be implemented in a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) in order to be applied to multiple files; simply replace `data.csv` with the `for` meta-variable then (demonstrated on variant 1. here):

```cmd
for %I in ("*.csv") do @(findstr /V "$" "%~I" > nul && echo/>> "%~I")
```

Remember that the `%`-signs need to be doubled when using this code in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).