# Insert line break after every command output in command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, eol

I want to save content of every text file in another output text using command prompt. I have used this command:

```
type ".\test\*.txt" > out.txt
```

But every output is appended in that text file. How do I introduce line break into output file after every text file read.

Comment: Unclear what you want, show current example as well as expected results. Adding a new line is easy, but not sure what your file looks like and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: You edited your question minutes after my comment and you ignored my request for clarity entirely?

Comment: If your individual files do not have CRLF line endings then your combined results file will not have separators between each. If you want additional CRLF's at the beginning and/or end of each, then your files must have those before you can do it with a single `type` command. The only way to introduce them where needed would be to code something which can get the content of each individual file, by reading and parsing it in such a way as the number of ending and/or beginning 'separators', then adding the appropriate number of those where needed. This is certainly not a simple one command task.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities, which I want to share with you:

1. Use [`type`](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) to return each file as is, then use [`findstr /V "$"`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) to find out whether the last line is terminated by a line-break and explicitly output one by [`echo/`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) if not, using the [conditional execution operator `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Write to output file:
    > "out.txt" (
        rem // Loop through input files to resolve wildcards:
        for %%F in (".\test\*.txt") do (
            rem // First type out the currently iterated file:
            type "%%~F"
            rem /* Let `findstr` detect whether there is a terminating line-break,
            rem    and conditionally append one if not: */
            > nul findstr /V /M "$" "%%~F" && echo/
        )
    )
   ```

   Caveats:

   - files must be less than 2 GiB in size?
2. Use [`find /V ""`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html), which appends a line-break to the last line if not present. Since `find` usually outputs a header that we do not need, provide the files via [input redirection `<`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) rather than as [arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Since redirection does not support [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html), let a [standard `for`-loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) resolve them:

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Write to output file:
    > "out.txt" (
        rem // Loop through input files since `<` does not support wildcards:
        for %%F in (".\test\*.txt") do (
            rem // Let `find` return all lines with a terminating line-break:
            < "%%~F" find /V ""
        )
    )
   ```

   Caveats:

   - files must be less than 2 GiB in size?
   - lines must be shorter than 4 KiB;
3. Use [`more /V ""`](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html), which appends a line-break to the last line if not present. To avoid a prompt after each file, let a [`for`-loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) resolve [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) rather than `more`:

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Write to output file:
    > "out.txt" (
        rem // Loop through input files since `more` awaits prompt per file on wildcards:
        for %%F in (".\test\*.txt") do (
            rem // Let `more` return all lines with a terminating line-break:
            more "%%~F"
        )
    )
   ```

   Caveats:

   - files must be less than 2 GiB in size?
   - files must contain less than 64 Ki lines;
   - lines must be shorter than 64 KiB;
   - <kbd>TABs</kbd> become expanded to <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>;
4. Use [`sort`](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html), which appends a line-break to the last line if not present. To avoid resorting of the lines, specify the character start position for sorting beyond the supported line length. Since `sort` then reverses the entire file, simply apply the command twice:

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Write to output file:
    > "out.txt" (
        rem // Loop through input files to not unintentionally rearrange lines:
        for %%F in (".\test\*.txt") do (
            rem // Let `sort` return all lines with a terminating line-break:
            sort "%%~F" /+65535 /REC 65535 | sort /+65535 /REC 65535
        )
    )
   ```

   Caveats:

   - files must be less than 2 GiB in size?
   - lines must be shorter than 64 KiB;
5. Read each file by [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and echo out each line, so each one, even the last one, will be terminated by a line-break; [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) is there to precede each line with its line number plus a colon in order for them not to appear empty to `for /F`, which would skip such lines; the prefix becomes then stripped off in the loop body:

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Write to output file:
    > "out.txt" (
        rem // Loop through input files since `for /F` does not support wildcards:
        for %%F in (".\test\*.txt") do (
            rem // Precede each line by line number plus `:`, then read each augmented line:
            for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%%~F"') do (
                rem // Store currently read augmented line:
                set "LINE=%%L"
                rem // Toggle delayed expansion to aviod loss of `!`:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Remove line number prefix and return current line with a line-break:
                echo(!LINE:*:=!
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
   ```

   Caveats:

   - files must be less than 2 GiB in size;
   - lines must be shorter than about 8 KiB;

Comment: There is a quite similar answer of mine, which I extracted the core information from: [Automation to add a LF and CR (EOL) to the end of multiple .csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645755)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague so I am guessing you just need to add as many echo's as you need / want.

This is a slight mod on one of the many examples given by `forfiles /?`

```
forfiles /p test /m "*.txt" /C "cmd /c type @file >>../out.txt &&echo. >>../out.txt &&echo. >>../out.txt
```

ensure you **rename or delete** any existing out.txt before you start

[image]