# Copy multiple csv file into one single file through batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have requirement to copy content of multiple csv file into one single file.

I used below command in my script.

`copy /b file1.csv + file2.csv+ file3.csv =result.csv`

I am able to append content of file into result file but first line of second file get copied  next to last line of the first file. Please find below example for clarification.

File 1

```
test,test,1234,test
test1,test1,12345,test1
```

File 2

```
test2,test2,123456,test2
test3,test4,12348,test3
```

result.csv

```
fname,lastname,personnumber,comment
test,test,1234,test
test1,test1,12345,test test2,test2,123456,test2
test3,test4,12348,test3
```

Expected output

result.csv

```
fname,lastname,personnumber,comment
test,test,1234,test
test1,test1,12345,test 
test2,test2,123456,test2
test3,test4,12348,test3
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: You need another file containing just CRLF to add between file1.csv and file2.csv.

Comment: Essentially your source files shoud use Windows CRLF line endings, and each end with one, _(you might call them empty lines)_.

Comment: actually my original code is -


copy /b NUL newline.csv
copy /b referral_payoutreport_rejection_hm.csv + newline.csv+ newline.csv + referral_payoutreport_rejection_Amount.csv + newline.csv + referral_payoutreport_rejection_Campus.csv + newline.csv + referral_payoutreport_rejection_Currency.csv + newline.csv + referral_payoutreport_rejection_Rehire.csv=REFRL_TALTCC_referralbonus_rejects_%NOW%.csv
 but it is not working as expected

Comment: No. You should create newline.csv this way: `echo/> newline.csv`. Also try removing **/b** switch...

Comment: @Aacini
 It add one blank line to file

Comment: Well, @sandeephimgire, what is a newline in your opinion then?? Anyway, why do your CSV file not contain a final line-break as they should? The creator of them should end each line, including the ultimate one, with a line-break. `copy` cannot magically insert line-breaks where they are missing, the command just concatenates the data, no more, no less…

Comment: Take a look at the following posts about how to handle files with a missing terminal line-break: [Insert line break after every command output in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70742617), [Automation to add a LF and CR (EOL) to the end of multiple .csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645755), [How to fix line break in text file batch output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56789970)